# Why are the direct summands obtained in the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID indecomposable?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated

The [structure theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) tells us that a finitely generated module $M$ over a principal ideal domain $R$ is isomorphic to a direct sum
$
\bigoplus _{i}R/(q_{i})
 $ where $ 
(
q_i
)
≠
R
(q_{i})\neq R$ and the
$(q_{i})$ are primary ideals. (In a PID, nonzero primary ideals are powers of primes, so $(q_{i})=(p_{i}^{{r_{i}}})=(p_{i})^{{r_{i}}}$).

I’m trying to see why each of the direct summands of the form $R/(q_{i})$ is an indecomposable module. The Wikipedia article seems to take that for granted and I haven’t found the reason myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q=p^n$, where $p$ is prime, then every proper submodule of $R/(q)$ is contained in $(p)/(q)$, so if $M,N \subsetneq R/(q)$ are two proper submodules, then $M,N \subseteq (p)/(q)$ and hence $M+N \subseteq (p)/(q)$, whence $M+N \subsetneq R/(q)$ is a proper submodule. Thus it is impossible that $R/(q)$ is a direct sum of two proper submodules.